# Downloading a Github repo without having git installed

Tags: git, github, automation

#### Background

I've setup a github repo for all my dotfiles: https://github.com/jaymody/dotfiles

The idea is that if I were to reset my machine (mac, although I have plans to adapt this for linux), I can basically download the repo, run a script and all my preferences/settings/apps are installed.

It works fine, except I realized in order to get the repository I'd need `git` already installed on my machine in order to `git clone` the repository. I don't like the idea of having to install git, when the whole purpose of the repo is to handle all that stuff (it installs git via homebrew).

I know you can `git archive` your repositories to create a .zip file, so a simple solution would be to store the .zip file in the repo itself and use `wget` or `curl` to get the zip. Although I feel like there has to be a better solution than that. I know you can also create archives for `tags` but the issue there is I would always want a tag for the latest commit of my repository.

#### Current Functionality

```sh
echo "export DOTFILES_ROOT=path/to/where/you/want/to/save/this/repo/" >> ~/.localrc
source ~/.localrc
git clone https://github.com/jaymody/dotfiles.git $DOTFILES_ROOT

cd $DOTFILES_ROOT
./bootstrap
```

#### Desired Functionality

```sh
echo "export DOTFILES_ROOT=path/to/where/you/want/to/save/this/repo/" >> ~/.localrc
source ~/.localrc
##### DOWNLOAD GITHUB REPO WITHOUT USING GIT HERE #####

cd $DOTFILES_ROOT
./bootstrap
```

**Note:** Obviously this is overkill and I would almost never need to use this functionality, but if I'm over-automating stuff, might as well go the full out.

Comment: What is the problem with just installing Git? You will need it for something else eventually.

Comment: What is the problem in downloading the repo? https://superuser.com/a/1309684

Comment: Download as zip: https://superuser.com/questions/1309683/how-do-i-download-my-whole-repository-from-gitlab

Comment: @mkrieger1 The idea is git (and all my other dev stuff) is installed and setup by the repo. So yes, it would be super easy to install git, but if I **truly** wanna automate this, I'm looking for some way to achieve this without git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to download it as a zip file instead.

```
wget https://github.com/jaymody/dotfiles/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I needed, I was under the impression that master wasn't archived by default.